# How to check if AWS ECR authentication token is not expired?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

I'm using `AWS ECR` for storing docker images. In my pipeline workflow, to push images to ECR, I need to get the authentication token to authenticate docker to AWS ECR. I do that by running the `aws ecr get-login-password` command. This all works well.

Now when I have to repeat this, ideally I don't want to get a new token immediately as the previous one is valid for 12 hours. How can I check if the existing token is still valid and not expired? Couldn't find any `aws cli` command to do this?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you do not want to obtain another token out of curiosity?

Comment: I'm happy to fetch another token, but not when the previously fetched token is still valid. Primarily because I don't want a lot of tokens to be floating in memory (or some temp location - not sure where it is stored) as we have a lot of users who gonna be building and pushing new images quite a few times in a day using the pipelines. So I don't want to fetch a new token every time because if I can do with, let's say 5 tokens fetched in a 12 hour window on 5 different build agents, I don't want to fetch 50 tokens. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @rockn-rolla - For your reuse case, what about (1) can't you call `aws ecr get-login-password`, after authentication error with previous token ? or (2) Maintain next refresh time i.e. after 12hrs for now and check that time before use of token?

Comment: @amitd Thanks! I myself am thinking around the 1st approach which you mentioned - I can make it work. As for your 2nd approach, could you gimme an example as to how you suggest to maintain the next refresh time?

Comment: +1 to the first approach (I was about to suggest to add some logic to "login on error"). Also, not sure if this could be helpful in your scenario? https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper (as a third option).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution posted by @Amit for auto-refreshing the token every 12 hours is one way to solve the problem, but we've settled on the approach suggested by others, which is using logic to "login on error".

A simple set of commands does this for us:

```
docker push <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<repository_name>:<version>

RESULT=$?

if [[ $RESULT == 0 ]]
then
  echo "Docker image pushed successfully using existing ECR authentication token"
  exit 0
else
  echo "Existing ECR authentication token not valid, fetching a new token"
  aws ecr get-login-password --region <region> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com
  docker push <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<repository_name>:<version>
fi
```

It is simple & On-demand. A token doesn't need to be fetched as long as it is not needed. This also enables us to not maintain cron expression on all the build agents in our workflow.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent multiple tokens and login from the same machine, we have implemented crone jobs to periodically refresh the tokens.

This is how we have resolved it for our deployments.

**Prerequisite :**

- AWS credentials are configured on the machine
- AWS cli is installed on the machine

**For Linux/Unix machine**

1. Create a shell script refreshToken.sh for a token refresh.

```
#!/bin/bash
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <YOUR_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

2. Put the file at location /opt/ecr-cred-refresh
3. Execute the following command to create a cron job to periodically refresh the token.

```
crontab -e
```

4. In the editor put the following text to refresh the token every 12 hour

```
0 */12 * * *  /etc/ecr-cred-refresh/refreshToken.sh
```

**For Windows machine**

1. Create a bat file refreshToken.bat for a token refresh.

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <YOUR_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

2. Create a scheduled task. Go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools
3. Click on task scheduler.

[image]

4. Click on the Action tab and select Create Task.

[image]

5. Provide basic details such as name etc.

[image]

6. Click on the trigger tab. Click on new.

[image]

7. Provide trigger details.

[image]

8. Now click on the action tab. and create a new action that will point to refreshToken.bat.

[image]

9. Save

Comment: That's very neat. Explains the 2nd approach. I would assume you'd already be aware that this would unnecessarily fetch tokens on weekends and holidays too.

Comment: Fo avoiding weekends please use the crone expression : 0 0 * * 1-5. Reference : https://crontab.guru/#0_0_*_*_1-5